# SQL server 2008 R2 - triggers insert multiple lines

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

hello i have the following trigger on a table

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_FxHedge_AuditTrail]
    ON [dbo].[FXHedge]
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
    IF ((SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),1,1)) & 4 = 4)
    DECLARE @oldManagementIntentId int
    DECLARE @newManagementIntentId int

    SET @oldManagementIntentId = (SELECT TOP(1)ManagementIntentId FROM Deleted);
    SET @newManagementIntentId = (SELECT TOP(1)ManagementIntentId FROM Inserted);

    IF ((@oldManagementIntentId  @newManagementIntentId) OR (@oldManagementIntentId IS   NULL AND @newManagementIntentId IS NOT NULL) OR (@oldManagementIntentId IS NOT NULL AND @newManagementIntentId IS NULL))
    INSERT INTO FxHedge_AuditTrail (EntityId
    ,ModificationDate
    ,PropertyChangedName
    ,OperationType
    ,ModifyBy
    ,OldValue
    ,NewValue)
    SELECT Inserted.Id
       ,Inserted.ModificationDate
       ,'ManagementIntentId'
       ,'UPDATE'
       ,Inserted.ModificationUser
       ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(250),Deleted.ManagementIntentId)
       ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(250),Inserted.ManagementIntentId)
     FROM Inserted,Deleted
```

whenever i run an update statement each updated line is inserted the number of updated row time

```
    UPDATE FXHedge SET ModificationDate = SYSDATETIME()
                  ,ManagementIntentId = 4
                  ,ModificationUser = 'AW4256' 
    WHERE FXHedge.Id in (780,803);
```

For this example each line is inserted twice in my audit table. If i had 3 modificated row each row would be inserted 3 times.

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You're not relating `inserted` and `deleted` together. In addition, for your procedural part, you're arbitrarily comparing one `ManagementIntentId` from `inserted` with another `ManagementIntentId` from `deleted`, with no guarantee that the two rows the values came from are related. I think this would be better:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_FxHedge_AuditTrail]
ON [dbo].[FXHedge]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO FxHedge_AuditTrail (EntityId
,ModificationDate
,PropertyChangedName
,OperationType
,ModifyBy
,OldValue
,NewValue)
SELECT i.Id
   ,i.ModificationDate
   ,'ManagementIntentId'
   ,'UPDATE'
   ,i.ModificationUser
   ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(250),d.ManagementIntentId)
   ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(250),i.ManagementIntentId)
 FROM Inserted i
         inner join
      Deleted d
         on
            i.ID = d.ID
 WHERE
     i.ManagementIntentId != d.ManagementIntentId or
     i.ManagementIntentId IS NULL and d.ManagementIntentId IS NOT NULL or
     i.ManagementIntentId IS NOT NULL and d.ManagementIntentId IS NULL
```

I'm not sure if the `COLUMNS_UPDATED` check was actually meant to be achieving anything useful (it had no effect in the current query) or was just part of pulling this trigger together from somewhere else, so I've removed that also.

Comment: the COLUMNS_UPDATED allow me to know which column has been updated. I only pasted a part of a longer trigger. Thank you for your assistance it went well. But i still don't understand something. Why am i obliged to join the inserted pseudo table and the deleted one?

Comment: Because `inserted` and `deleted` contain *multiple* rows - one for each row affected by your `UPDATE`. As to the `COLUMNS_UPDATED`, as it stands in your question, all that it affects (without being followed by a `BEGIN...END` block) is the following `DECLARE` of `@oldManagementIntentId`. But since `DECLARE`s don't respect control flow, it had *no* effect on this query.